# Intent message passing confusion

Tags: java, android, android-intent, message

I am a little confused with intent and message passing in android.Basically my current predicament:

A screen is shown to user displaying list of animals, when a user clicks a row, e.g. a Tiger, information about this animal will be displayed on the next screen/activity.

I have the framework for the application largely taken care of, so when a user selects from animal list they are brought to the Animal activity/class, but at this stage it is just a generic mockup.

How can I go about telling the application that TIGER was selected, and to show tiger data to user.My approach thus far

User clicks item on list and activity is called:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Intent animalIntent = new Intent(this, Animal.class);
    startActivity(animalIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon @PhilLello, once you use Intent.setExtra(), you can retrieve the value in your activity with:

```
string animal;
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    animal = extras.getString("animal");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!I actually have one more question, how exactly can I tell which row the user has clicked.I mean, I wont know they have clicked Tiger, they may have clicked parrot.Is this done via the onListItemClick(int position)?This would imply that I am using a static list, which is the case, im just wondering if there may be a better approach

Comment: You actually would use the last argument: long id to reference the row id clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to your intent, so before calling startActivity you can do:

```
animalIntent.putExtra("myApp.chosenAnimal","Tiger");
```

You can use different data types in place of the Tiger string above, an integer representing the animals ID, a Tiger object, etc.

Now in your example there, the "Animal" class would have to be an activity, that is the activity that is loaded once the intent is processed. If Animal is just a POJO you might need a new activity to show your specific animal.

Once inside the Animal activity, you can check the contents of the passed Intents with:

```
Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
String selectedAnimal = incomingIntent.getStringExtra("myApp.chosenAnimal");
```

note the "myApp.chosenAnimal" in the incoming intent area matches that in animalIntent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intent.setExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)("animal", "TIGER") before firing the Intent.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question before and found the following to work for me. In the activity that you want to send data put the following.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(KEY,String);
i.putExtra(KEY2,String);
```

When you want to receive this information run the following.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String temp = extras.getString(KEY);
String temp2 = extras.getString(KEY2);
```

Hope this helps